# class.active is not changing through (click) event handler

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I'm trying to create a kind of toggle action when two buttons in angular.

[Buttons to code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nEOWz.png)

So, what should happen is when I click trending, burst should appear as inactive and vice versa. I'm trying to do this through `[class.active]` on angular:

```html
<div class="col-6">
        <button [class.active]="burstButton" (click)="onTabChange()" clickable>Burst</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <button [class.active]="trendingButton"  (click)="onTabChange()" clickable>Trending</button>
    </div>
```

I tried to do this by declaring two boolean variables, one for each button:

```js
public trendingButton: boolean = true;
public burstButton: boolean = false;
```

And handle the click event through a function obviously:

```js
onTabChange() {

    console.log('Hello from ontabchange')
    if (this.trendingButton) {
      this.burstButton = false;
    } else {
      this.burstButton = true;
    }

}
```

My problem is, no matter what button I click, nothing happens. The log print on `onTabChange` appears in the console when I click either button so I don't understand what's going on.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic in your `onTabChange` seems wrong. The value of `this.trendingButton` will always be `true`, and thus  `this.burstButton` will always be assigned the `false` value from the first branch of your if-else.

Most importantly, have you defined the `.active` class in your CSS file?
If not, then what you see is the expected behavior.

Comment: Lol I was so dumb for not realising this. Hahhaa I'm laughing too hard thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your condition should be like this...

```
trendingButton: boolean = false;
burstButton: boolean = false;
    
    onTabChange() {
        console.log('Hello from ontabchange')
        if (!this.trendingButton) {
          this.trendingButton= true;
        } else {
          this.trendingButton= false;
        }
if (!this.burstButton) {
          this.burstButton= true;
        } else {
          this.burstButton= false;
        }`enter code here`
    
    }
```

and please make sure that you have defined your "active" class in CSS

Answer (score -1):

You have wrong logic in `onTabChange` and one extra variable. Make html code execute onTabChange with name of button:

```
<div class="col-6">
        <button [class.active]="currentButton === 'burst'" (click)="onTabChange('burst')" clickable>Burst</button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <button [class.active]="currentButton === 'trending'"  (click)="onTabChange('trending')" clickable>Trending</button>
    </div>
```

int TS file:

```
public current: string = 'burst';
onTabChange(buttonName: string) {

    console.log('Hello from ontabchange')
    this.currentButton = buttonName;

}
```

Hope this helps.